# Q: What's the difference between MediaCodecVideoEncoder and HardwareVideoEncoder in webrtc Android sdk?

Tags: webrtc

I noticed that a new class `HardwareVideoEncoder` was introduced recently, what's the relationship between it and `MediaCodecVideoEncoder`? Is it planed to replace `MediaCodecVideoEncoder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading commit history of WebRTC during the last two months, I think that `HardwareVideoEncoder` is designed as a new way to use `MediaCodec`.

So it should replace the older `MediaCodecVideoEncoder`, but not now, it's still under development and not ready yet.

[Initial commit about it](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/e2410e9ab474abc1ef43bc658f76971eaf94fb07):

> Interfaces for injectable video codecs.
>
> These interfaces will be used by the future refactoring that will
> allow clients to provide custom codec implementations.

Comment: Upvoted. I saw your VideoCRE project on GitHub. But it uses old webrtc lib to record video as mp4. Do you have any other demo which uses the latest webrtc library?